# difference in bigquery performance between partition and full table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a ~1 Billion rows in a 25 partitions (40m each) union, and in 1 full table.
I run a query that calculate distinct counts, usually it find the data on 1-4 partitions. ( the query is dynamic) based on a where clause.
same query runs 30sec on the union of all tables, vs 50sec on the full table. same GB processed. 
first of all, great performance :-)
the questions are:
1. what are the principals in terms of **performance only** to use union vs 1 big table? is partition table always faster?
2. if it uses only few partitions, why does it charge me for same GB? this mean that I will have to dynamically construct the query to choose the right partition... which is a burden. ( I understand you dont have an an SQL like optimizer, but if I need to manage partitions, shouldn't I benefit from it?)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For both of the queries you've described, BigQuery still processes *all* of your data. For the unioned query, the layout of the data may be somewhat advantageous, but it doesn't mean that BigQuery is doing any less work -- hence the fact that you are charged the same. If you can, as you suggested, construct a query that only uses the required partitions, this will be less data to process and therefore less expensive.

It is difficult to predict whether having all of your data in a single table or spreading it across multiple tables and doing union queries is going to improve performance. For this particular query, it sounds like union is faster, for other queries, such as ones that may be doing more work that is spread across the partitions, it might be slower.

I'd say a rule of thumb is that if you can pre-filter the data by figuring out which partitions are going to be needed, you're going to be better off, if only because you can then run less expensive queries. Your queries are unlikely to be slower over smaller data, and they may often be faster.

I should also note that improving the syntax for selecting multiple tables in a query (e.g letting people specify date ranges, or wildcards in their queries) is one of our most frequently requested features, and there is a good chance we'll get to that fairly soon. How are your tables partitioned? What would make it simpler to specify the right tables for your queries?

Comment: sorry for the delay, the tables partitioned by sharding 50m rows in each, based on months more or less, I can specify some of them, but that would complicate the the SQL since the range is dynamic.